# After login to phpmyadmin(ubuntu15.04), no 'phpmyadmin' option in the list

Tags: php, lamp, phpmyadmin

How can I resolve this problem?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the entry

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = 'phpmyadmin';
```

in `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` via

```
sudo sed -i '/hide_db.*=.*phpmyadmin/d' /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

Restart your http server.